# How does one get an Epson Stylus SX425W to work with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, epson

Have tried down loading it from computer but it will only go so far then says that there is an error see /var/log/jockey.log.  The printer will respond to the command print but will not print, it takes all the paper and puts it through the machine until it runs out of supply

Comment: Not sure what `/var/log/jockey.log` is, but I have an EPSON SX535WD and I simply added it to the CUPS configuration and it works fine. Can you provide more details? Since it's a wireless printer, I' assuming you're using it that way, in which case CUPS should be able to detect it.

Comment: I have an Epson Stylus SX425W, with Ubuntu 12.04.1 and can confirm the same problem. We had it working with an old ubuntu using a proprietary driver downloaded from somewhere before. Can't remember where I got it though. Will look around.

Answer (score 0):

I had this working with an older version of ubuntu, by installing this driver, which can be found on the web:

epson-inkjet-printer-nx420_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb

My notes tell me that these drivers don't work:

Stylus SX420W and Stylus TX420W,

and that the one that did work was called:

TX420 NX420

However, when I try installing this now, it says it's already installed that driver, and it won't let me choose a different printer type.

So some level of messing about may help here.

---

Aha! Go to printer properties, and change the make and model to Epson Stylus TX420W Series - epson-inkjet-printer 1.0.0-1lsb3.2 (Seiko Epson Corporation LSB 3.2).

Then it seems to work fine!